# How do I "or" each column in a DataFrame with a vector?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, logical-operators

Let's say I have the data below:

```
try:
    from StringIO import StringIO
except ImportError:
    from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
from numpy import uint8

vector = pd.Series([1, 0, 0, 1])

df = pd.read_table(StringIO("""a    b    c
1   0   0
1   1   1
0   1   1
1   1   0"""), sep="\s+", dtype=uint8, header=0)
```

How do I "or" the vector with each column in the df?

I know I can make a partial function with "or" and my vector and apply it to the df, but this is probably unidiomatic and needlessly time-consuming. What is the pandas way?

Come to think of it, the idiomatic way is probably a lambda... Is there no binary operator for this, like `dataframe.div(series)`? ([Binary DF operations](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#id4))

I'd like `dataframe.or(vector)`...

Comment: Are there any speed gains to be had by using bools btw? Doing this on gigabytes of data...

Comment: Can you show the time consuming method you are talking about? Using partial function .

Comment: Too much typing :) Partial is in the functools module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pass the DataFrame and the (column) vector directly to [`np.logical_or`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.logical_or.html):

```
>>> np.logical_or(df, vector[:, None])
       a     b     c
0   True  True  True
1   True  True  True
2  False  True  True
3   True  True  True
```

Note that this returns a DataFrame of boolean values; you can cast back to a numeric datatype if you prefer.

Comment: Don't understand the `[:,None]` - why is it needed here?

Comment: For NumPy's broadcasting to work, we need to add a new dimension to `vector`; without it, NumPy tries to broadcast the vector down the columns (axis 0) instead of along the rows (axis 1). This raises an error as the vector has more elements than their are columns.

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of numpy's broadcasting, bitwise-or'ing the underlying numpy array (`df.values`) against the vector:

```
import numpy as np
new_values = df.values.astype(bool) | vector.values[:,np.newaxis].astype(bool)
```

This results with a numpy array, not a dataframe, but you can easily re-construct the dataframe:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame(new_values, columns = df.columns)
```

Since this approach directly let's numpy do the computations, it is likely the fastest.

Comment: Great info, but accepted the other since no recreation of df required. Thanks!